# JavaScript - how to get value by using a JSON ID that is in another JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

The exercise is as follows:

> It is required to obtain an Arrangement with the names of clients ordered from highest to lowest by the TOTAL sum of the balances.

with these javascript objects:

```
const clients = [
{ id: 1, taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'},
{ id: 2, taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'},
{ id: 3, taxNumber: '73826497', name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA'},
{ id: 4, taxNumber: '88587715', name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ'},
{ id: 5, taxNumber: '94020190', name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS'},
{ id: 6, taxNumber: '99804238', name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' }
];
```

and:

```
const accounts = [
{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 },
{ clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },
{ clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },
{ clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },
{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },
{ clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },
{ clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },
{ clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },
{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },
{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },
{ clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }
]
```

So far, I get the total sum of the salaries of each client. in this way:

```
function sortClientsTotalBalances() {

var map = accounts.reduce(function(map, account) {

    var clientId = account.clientId
    var balance = +account.balance
    map[clientId] = (map[clientId] || 0) + balance

    return map
  }, {})

  console.log(map)

var obj = clients;

    var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(name) {


    return {
      fullName: name,
      totalbalance: map[name]
    }
  })
    console.log(array)  
 };
```

obtaining the following:

[image]

but I cannot find the way to get the corresponding name of the client that is in the other json, and join it to the final query, which so far only shows the id with the total, since they are in the same json.

desired result

```
  0: { name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS', totalbalance: 8340 },
  1: { name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ', totalbalance: 5000},
  2: { name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA', totalbalance: 7500 },
  3: { name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ', totalbalance: 6500},
  4: { name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS', totalbalance: 9300},
  5: { name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' , totalbalance: 8500}
```

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: they are not "JSON's" ... they are javascript objects ... which makes it easier of course

Comment: I'd first change clients to be in the form of `{ 1: {taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'}, 2: {taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'}}` - this is easy to do, and will make the next step simple as well

Comment: `It is required to obtain....` can you show the **exact** format of the required output, rather than a vague description of it

Comment: Right! This is the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach by starting with the clients and creating a client object that represents your final output. Then it's a simple matter of calling `forEach` on the accounts and add the balance to the client object.

For example:

```js
const clients = [{ id: 1, taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'},{ id: 2, taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'},{ id: 3, taxNumber: '73826497', name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA'},{ id: 4, taxNumber: '88587715', name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ'},{ id: 5, taxNumber: '94020190', name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS'},{ id: 6, taxNumber: '99804238', name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' }];
const accounts = [{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 },{ clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 },{ clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 },{ clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 },{ clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 },{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 },{ clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 },{ clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 },{ clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 },{ clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 },{ clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 },{ clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 },{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 },{ clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 },{ clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 },{ clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 },{ clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 },{ clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 },{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 },{ clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 },{ clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 },{ clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 },{ clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 }]
     
// make client object that looks like final result
const client_obj = clients.reduce((a,c) => {
    a[c.id] = {name: c.name, totalbalance: 0}
    return a
}, {})

// just add balances to appropriate value of that object
accounts.forEach(item => client_obj[item.clientId].totalbalance += item.balance)

// sort object objvalues 
console.log(Object.values(client_obj).sort((a,b) => a.totalbalance - b.totalbalance))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pop this chunk on the end of your function?

```
for (var i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    //find the corresponding name of the client
    for (var j=0;j<clients.length();j++){
       if (array[i].fullName==clients[j].id){
           array[i].name=clients[j].name;
       }
    }
    //Rearrange fullName and ID
    array[i].id=parseInt(array[i].fullName);
    delete array[i].fullName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Object.keys` on the object `map` you get an array of IDs because that's how you construct it (the object `map`) with `Array#reduce`. So when you call `Array#map` on that array of IDs, the value that get passed to the callback is the ID not the name. Slightly change `Array#map` code to fetch the name from the `clients` array like so:

```
var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(id) {
    var client = clients.find(function(client) {           // find the client from the array clients
        return client.id == id;                            // ... whose id is the same as the current id
    });

    return {
        fullName: client.name,                             // use that client name
        totalbalance: map[id]                              // access the balance using id
    };
});
```

**Example:**

```js
const clients = [ { id: 1, taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'}, { id: 2, taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'}, { id: 3, taxNumber: '73826497', name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA'}, { id: 4, taxNumber: '88587715', name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ'}, { id: 5, taxNumber: '94020190', name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS'}, { id: 6, taxNumber: '99804238', name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' } ];

const accounts = [ { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 }, { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 }, { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 }, { clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 }, { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 }, { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 }, { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 }, { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 } ];

var map = accounts.reduce(function(map, account) {
    var clientId = account.clientId;
    var balance = +account.balance;
    map[clientId] = (map[clientId] || 0) + balance;

    return map;
}, {});

var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(id) {
    var client = clients.find(function(client) {           // find the client from the array clients
        return client.id == id;                            // ... whose id is the same as the current id
    });

    return {
        fullName: client.name,                             // use that client name
        totalbalance: map[id]                              // access the balance using id
    };
});

console.log(array);
```

---

Another approach would be to turn the `clients` array into an object where the keys are the IDs and the values are the names so there won't be a need to use `Array#find`:

```
var clientsById = clients.reduce(function(obj, client) {
    obj[client.id] = client.name;
    return obj;
}, {});

var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(id) {
    return {
        fullName: clientsById[id],                         // use id to get the name from the object clientsById
        totalbalance: map[id]                              // access the balance using id
    };
});
```

**Example:**

```js
const clients = [ { id: 1, taxNumber: '86620855', name: 'HECTOR ACUÑA BOLAÑOS'}, { id: 2, taxNumber: '7317855K', name: 'JESUS RODRIGUEZ ALVAREZ'}, { id: 3, taxNumber: '73826497', name: 'ANDRES NADAL MOLINA'}, { id: 4, taxNumber: '88587715', name: 'SALVADOR ARNEDO MANRIQUEZ'}, { id: 5, taxNumber: '94020190', name: 'VICTOR MANUEL ROJAS LUCAS'}, { id: 6, taxNumber: '99804238', name: 'MOHAMED FERRE SAMPER' } ];

const accounts = [ { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 15000 }, { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 18000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 135000 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 5600 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 23000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 15000 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 3, balance: 45900 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 19000 }, { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 51000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 1, balance: 89000 }, { clientId: 1, bankId: 2, balance: 1600 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 3, balance: 37500 }, { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 19200 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 3, balance: 10000 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 2, balance: 5400 }, { clientId: 3, bankId: 1, balance: 9000 }, { clientId: 4, bankId: 3, balance: 13500 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 1, balance: 38200 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 17000 }, { clientId: 1, bankId: 3, balance: 1000 }, { clientId: 5, bankId: 2, balance: 600 }, { clientId: 6, bankId: 1, balance: 16200 }, { clientId: 2, bankId: 2, balance: 10000 } ];

var map = accounts.reduce(function(map, account) {
    var clientId = account.clientId;
    var balance = +account.balance;
    map[clientId] = (map[clientId] || 0) + balance;

    return map;
}, {});

var clientsById = clients.reduce(function(obj, client) {
    obj[client.id] = client.name;
    return obj;
}, {});

var array = Object.keys(map).map(function(id) {
    return {
        fullName: clientsById[id],                         // use id to get the name from the object clientsById
        totalbalance: map[id]                              // access the balance using id
    };
});

console.log(array);
```

**Note:** You still need to sort the resulting array using `Array#sort`. I won't spoil that for you.

Comment: Absolutely correct!, I just needed a guide and you have been successful! thank you very much! :D

Comment: @DemaroCreate You're welcome! I've fixed some typos and added working snippetts to the answer. Check them out!

Answer (score 0):

I would map to wanted result like this :

```
function sortClientsTotalBalances(clients, accounts) {
    // Every client are mapped to wanted data result.
    let results = clients.map((client) => {
      // Here I get client total balance by using reduce
      let clientBalance = accounts.reduce((acc, account) => {
        if (account.clientId === client.id ) {
          acc += account.balance;
        }
        return acc; 
      }, 0);
    // Here I create wanted result object;
    let result = {
      id: client.id,
      name: client.name,
      totalBalance: clientBalance 
    };
    return result;
  });

  // Return sorted results
  return results.sort((a, b) => a.totalBalance < b.totalBalance );
}
```